# How to receive/fetch arguements in Sikuli

Tags: command-line, jython, sikuli

How to do I pass arguments in Sikuli?

```
PATH-TO-SIKULI/sikuli-ide.exe -r xxxx.sikuli --args a1 a2 a3
```

Is how I am passing the arguments,.

How do I receive them in my Sikuli script?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to cpburnz, I was able to send and recieve arguements.

```
import sys.argv
sys.argv[1]
sys.argv[2]
sys.argv[3]
```

I ran the script as:

```
D:\Sikuli\Sikuli\runIDE.cmd -r D:\sikuli_test.sikuli --args arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to run Sikuli from Command Line](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/010-command-line.html#cmdoption--args):

> `--args <arguments>`
>
> > specify the arguments passed to Jython’s sys.argv

This means you can access the arguments from `sys.argv`. E.g.,

```python
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
```

Note that the first argument `argv[0]` is the name of the script, and can be ignored. All of the following arguments `argv[1:]` are the arguments you specified.

Comment: I am running the script like: 

runIDE.cmd -r D:\sikuli_test.sikuli -- arg1

I get the following error:

[error] script stopped with error in line 5
[error] TypeError ( type(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String )

Comment: @Mayank Are you running *Sikuli* or *SikuliX*? *Sikuli* uses the form `--args <args>` while *SikuliX* uses the form `-- <args>`.

Comment: @Mayank Looking up [TypeError ( type(): 1st arg can't be coerced to String )](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/234855), it looks like this error is unrelated to getting arguments passed from the command line. You should make a new question including the error, the sikuli script that produces the error, and the command line used to run the script.

Comment: I am using Sikuli, I get an error which says 'No module named argparse') 
Is there to fetch arguements in Sikuli?

Comment: @Mayank In that case, you'll have to use `sys.argv` directly. *argparse* was added in Python 2.7. You must be running Jython 2.5 or older then. See my update.